# footmisc + marginfix + todonotes = error

Tags: margins, article, marginpar, todonotes, footmisc

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\todo{test}
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` leads to a compilation error:

```
! Package marginfix Error: lost some margin notes.

See the marginfix package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \end{document}
                  
? Q
```

Unfortunately, the explanation in § 13 of the documentation of marginfix says nothing to me. Having a bit more text, say,

```
\begin{document}
test

\todo{test}

test
\end{document}
```

doesn't help.

Used versions:

- pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)
- LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
- L3 programming layer <2022-06-02>
- article 2021/10/04 v1.4n
- footmisc 2022/03/08 v6.0d
- marginfix 2020/05/06 v1.2
- todonotes 2021/06/04 v1.1.5

This is the current Debian testing TeX Live.  In Debian stable TeX Live, the aforementioned code works (or at least worked several months ago).

Who is the culprit and what to do?

Comment: I get the error in 2022 and 2021 but not 2020

Comment: New version of the same bug: http://github.com/FrankMittelbach/fmitex-footmisc/issues/10 , http://github.com/shicks/marginfix/issues/19 , and https://github.com/henrikmidtiby/todonotes/issues/71 .

Answer (score 1):

You can use an earlier `footmisc`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}[=v5]
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\todo{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: FYI, a new report of the same bug: http://github.com/FrankMittelbach/fmitex-footmisc/issues/10 , http://github.com/shicks/marginfix/issues/19 , and https://github.com/henrikmidtiby/todonotes/issues/71 .

Answer (score 0):

marginfix patches into `\@combinefloats` and footmisc uses a new output routine where this no longer works (or rather has no effect it it comes *after* footmisc. So instead of using the old version of footmisc one can simply load marginfix first.

Given that the the output routine of LaTeX will change (along the lines that footmisc already uses, but with additional hooks for other packages) the low-level patching for something like `\@combinefloats` the way it is done by marginfix has no future and should be replaced at some point in the future when appropriate hooks are made availabe for "safe" patching.

By the way, the problem is unrelated to todonotes and you can drop the package and use a `\marginpar` to generate the error.